# Fiware Orion: unique entities ids for different users

Tags: fiware-orion

My application controls "sensors", and uses Orion for managing user's sensors as entities.
For example, an entity is defined as:

```
{
  id: "MySensor"
  type: "Sensor"
...
}
```

The sensor name is encoded as the entity id.
However, with this system, two different users cannot have the same sensor name.
How should I do to allow different users to have the same entity id?

I could use the ServicePath feature and put the user name in it.
But I was always reluctant to use the ServicePath because it behaves so weirdly:

- very confusing when two entities have the same id in two different service paths. Both entities will be returned, without possibility to distinguish them.
- sometime you need to specify the servicePath header (UPDATE, DELETE operations), sometime not (GET which assume a wildcard servicePath).
- usage of HTTP headers (while servicepath is clearly at the level of id and types)

As an alternative solution, I could encode the user name in the entity id: `MySensor-userx`. But this is also quite awkward :)

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

The only way of generating different entity ids for different users would be to use some kind of structured string, for instance a URN, example

urn:ngsi-ld:Sensor:MyUser:A2345

being A234 the sensor identifier and MyUser the user identifier.

Hope this helps